# How to transfer Address Book from Outlook 2003 to Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, address-book

I purchased a new computer with Windows 7 and transfered my programs and files. I had been running Win XP SP3  on my old system using Outlook 2003. I am now using Outlook 2010.

My email works ok, but it did not transfer my personal contacts address book.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2003 click File then Import Export the Export to a file.  I use PST as file type.  Click Next and then select Contacts.  Click Next and Pick a destination.  Also click include subfolders if your address book has any.

Once exported, go to Outlook 2010 and click File Import Export and then Import from another program then pick Personal Folder (PST) and browse to the PST created in teh export process. and select if you want duplicates imported.  Follow the prompts